# Integrating the remainder of $\frac{1}{(1+x)}$ by hands

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

It can be easily shown, by simply sum everything up, that$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}=\frac{(1+x)}{1+x}-\frac{(x+x^2)}{1+x}+\frac{(x^2+x^3)}{1+x}-...+\frac{[(-1)^{n-1}](x^{n-1}+x^n)}{1+x}+\frac{[(-1)^{n}]x^n}{1+x}$$
But also by using the maclaurin's formula, I can get
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3...+[(-1)^{n-1}]x^{n-1}+\int_0^xf^n(t)\cdot\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt$$
Because the rest of the terms are the same, I can get
$$\int_0^xf^n(t)\cdot\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt=\frac{[(-1)^{n}]x^n}{1+x}$$

---

[Question]: If I choose to directly integrate $\int_0^xf^n(t)\cdot\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt$ by hands, without using the trick above, how am I suppose to get the answer ?

Comment: Looks like this is just [Cauchy's formula for repeated integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration), which is honestly just the usual proof of the integral remainder formula for Taylor's theorem.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, thanks, but by using Cauchy's formula for repeated integration, I get
$$\int_0^xf^n(t)\cdot\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt=\{f^{-(n)}[f^n(t)]\}\Biggr|_0^x=\left\{f^{-(n)}\left[(-1)^{n}\frac{n!}{(1+x)^{n+1}}\right]\right\}\Biggr|_0^x$$, which is still hard to track by hands

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're saying, but integrating $1/(1+x)^n$ repeatedly isn't very complicated.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, Ah you're right, I thought with $\Biggr|_0^x$ it would be hard to do by hands, but I forgot I can use induction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment by SimplyBeautifulArt, I have worked out the detail of this integral:

---

By using Cauchy's formula for repeated integration, I can get
$$\int_0^xf^n(t)\cdot\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt=f^{-(n)}[f^n(t)]\Biggr|_0^x=f^{-(n)}\left[(-1)^{n}\frac{n!}{(1+t)^{n+1}}\right]\Biggr|_0^x=(-1)^{n}(n!)\left[f^{-(n)}\frac{1}{(1+t)^{n+1}}\Biggr|_0^x\right]$$

For $f^{-(n)}\left[\frac{1}{(1+t)^{n+1}}\right]\Biggr|_0^x$, the following induction can be computed by hands
$$\begin{cases}f^{-1}\Biggr|_0^x=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n(1+x)^n}\\f^{-2}\Biggr|_0^x=\frac{x}{n}-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}+\frac{1}{n(n-1)(1+x)^{n-1}}\\f^{-3}\Biggr|_0^x=\frac{x^2}{2n}-\frac{x}{n(n-1)}+\frac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)}-\frac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)(1+x)^{n-2}}\\\vdots\\\vdots\\f^{-n}\Biggr|_0^x=\frac{x^n+x^{n-1}}{n!(1+x)}-\frac{x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}}{n!(1+x)}+\frac{x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}}{n!(1+x)}-...+\frac{(-1)^{n}(x+1)}{n!(1+x)}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cdot1}{n!(1+x)}=\frac{x^n}{n!(1+x)}\end{cases}$$

Substitute $f^{-n}\Biggr|_0^x=\frac{x^n}{n!(1+x)}$ back to $\left\{(-1)^{n}n!\left[f^{-(n)}\frac{1}{(1+t)^{n+1}}\Biggr|_0^x\right]\right\}$, it can be shown that
$$\int_0^xf^n(t)\cdot\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt=\frac{[(-1)^{n}]x^n}{1+x}$$